# Mautic - Fatal error: Class 'Mautic\Auth\ApiAuth' not found

Tags: php, mautic

I'm having an issue on [Mautic php api-library](https://github.com/mautic/api-library) installation as described [the docs](https://developer.mautic.org/?php#libraries). I download the zip as mentioned above.

> Download the package from Github. Extract then include the following code in your project:

I download the lib folder, which contains a lot of php files and added it to my project, and them create a simple php file.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/Mautic/MauticApi.php'; // yes, the path is correct
use Mautic\Auth\ApiAuth;
session_start();
$settings = array(
    'userName'   => '...',
    'password'   => '...'
);

// Initiate the auth object specifying to use BasicAuth
$initAuth = new ApiAuth();
$auth = $initAuth->newAuth($settings, 'BasicAuth');
```

The MauticApi.php file was found but i got the fallowing error when executing.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mautic\Auth\ApiAuth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 11

I thinks that all files inside the lib folder must be included recursively. but the docs tells to only include the MauticApi.php file. Is that correct? what should i do?

Server info:

```
PHP Version 5.6.33
cURL support enabled 
cURL Information 7.56.0 
Server API Apache 2.0 Handler
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using composer to install the library and just include the autoload file. Manually adding the library will force you to include all the files in your script.